# Why "wait" is used instead of "have waited"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-simple

Why **wait** is used in the following text instead of **have waited**?

> Ben: Aw, I can’t believe it. I **wait** all school year to go on this
>   trip, and now the queen of cooties is along for the ride.
>
> Gwen: Hey, I
>   had my own vacation already all planned out, too, you know. (pulls out
>   her schedule) Each activity is color-coded so I never do the same
>   thing two days in a row. Now, I’m stuck with my geekazoid cousin going
>   camping for three months.
>
> Excerpt from *[And Then There Were Alternate 10](https://ben10fanfiction.fandom.com/wiki/And_Then_There_Were_Alternate_10)* (a Ben 10 fan fiction)

Answer (score 1):

You could use have waited, and it would be grammatically correct. But in this case, the *dialogue is in between two cousins and is **informal***, so it would sound unnatural if Ben were to use 'have waited'. It makes more sense if you think about it as a colloquial dialogue because that is how we speak on a day-to-day basis. Hope this helps.